# Cache function or view?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to use `django-rest-framework` with cache.

```
@cache_page(10 * 60)
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_num(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        res = ["ok"]
        return Response(res)
```

It works well.

So actually I want to cache not `view` but `function`

```
@cache_page(10 * 60)
def getCalc(num):
    return num * 10


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_num(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        res = getCalc(request.query_params.get('num'))
        return Response(res)
```

There comes error `TypeError: _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Is it possible to use cache for `function`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [cachetools](https://pypi.org/project/cachetools/)

```
@cachetools.func.ttl_cache(maxsize=10,ttl=10*6)
def getCalc(num):
    return num * 10
```

**maxsize** depends on your requirement.

Comment: Good answer. However, note that this doesn't store the cached value using Django's cache - it stores the cached value as a Python object in the local process. This means three things: 1) Invocations of this function on different worker processes will not share a cache. 2) More memory will be used in the local process for caching. 3) Cachetools is typically faster than Django's cache framework because it does not need to unpickle anything or load anything over the network. You can find documentation about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/

Comment: @Mahamudul Hasan I can make it with this library and

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't have a built-in decorator for caching `functions` using the cache-framework.  You have three options:

### A) Python's built-in `functools.cache` decorator:

Python's built-in `functools.cache` (or `functools.lru_cache`) decorator  will only cache in local memory, which means the cache entries aren't shared between processes, and don't persist.  (If you need a `timeout`, you can use `cachetools` library as mentioned in another answer)

This technique be sufficient in certain cases (e.g., if your function is fairly inexpensive), but may not be ideal if your function is expensive (e.g., does complex database queries) and you need to minimize cache misses.

### B) Django's Low Level Cache API

You can use Django's [low-level cache api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api), and `get()/set()` cache entries directly.  E.g., you would do:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def getCalc(num):
    key = f'getCalc__{num}'
    val = cache.get(key)
    
    if val is not None:
        return val

    val = num * 10  # your expensive computation goes here
    cache.set(key, val, 10*60)  # cache timeout: 10 minutes
    return val
```

### C) The `django-cache-memoize` library

The simplest option may be to use the [django-cache-memoize](https://django-cache-memoize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which provides a `cache_memoize` decorator built using the Django's low-level cache api described above.  It is analogous to `cache_page`, but for `functions` instead of `views`.  Then you can simply do:

```
from cache_memoize import cache_memoize

@cache_memoize(10*60)
def getCalc(num):
    return num * 10  # your expensive computation goes here
```

The library documentation explains how you can customize the cache key as well as other available options.

Answer (score 0):

you can add request to function parameters:

```
@cache_page(10 * 60)
def getCalc(request, num):
    return num * 10


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_num(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        res = getCalc(request, request.query_params.get('num'))
        return Response(res)
```